# Is there a way to program AWS Athena queries to run every 15 minutes?

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I built a SQL query in AWS Athena, but I want it to automatically run every 15 minutes without me having to do anything. I am aware that Lambda would be good for this, but I have no experience with programming, or Lambda, and am at a complete loss on how to even start.

How do I get started with Lambda in order to do this? Or is there another way to automatically schedule the query to run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From experience, running a python Lambda using `boto3` is pretty straightforward, especially for tasks like the one you mention. Here is a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/y4e/03d5d783ac160fc0f657d5ef038a562f#file-athena-lambda-function-py) that's self contained and could get you on track to developing your own. The only requirement is [installing `boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation).

The docs have [a tutorial that details how to set a Cloudwatch event that'll trigger your Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html), and also on the docs is [a page explaining Cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/reference-cron-and-rate-expressions.html) (responsible for actually scheduling your trigger), but I can say in advance that for an "every 15-minutes" trigger, your Cron expression could be

```
cron(0/15 * * * ? *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a query every 15 min is absolutely possible. To get started with Lambda in general the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html) is great. I would suggest from personal experience that you you look into something like the Servereless Framework to make your life easier. [Serverless AWS Tutorial](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/) should get you up and running and help you manage the build, deploy, and invocation of your lambda.

Example of a YAML configuration for a lambda to run every 15 min through the Serverless Framework which you would use to build, deploy, and invoke

```
my_awesome_query:
    handler: src/my_query_lambda.run
    timeout: 270
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0/15 * * * ? *)
          enabled: true
```